# How to find opening and closing body tags in JSP

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a simple font increase/decrease function which works fine on my local machine but when I integrate this in JSP it stops working. Then I download that page from the internet and I kept my js before `</body>` tag and it starts working fine.

However the battle is that this JSP has no `body` start tag and end tag so how can I handle this.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function getSize() {
    size = $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a span,#menu li a').css("font-size");
    size = parseInt(size) + 1;
    //$( "#font-size" ).text(  size  );
  }

  //get inital font size
  getSize();

  $(".fontSizePlus").on("click", function() {
    if ((size + 1) < 22) {
      $($('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a span,#menu li a,.right-description,.right-description a,.newsboard h4,.event-right-description h3 a,.event-right-description span,span.heading-text,.heading-text,.recent-files ul li a,.recent-files ul li span,.forums ul li span,.forums ul li a,.activity-feed ul li span,.activity-feed ul li a,.wiki ul li span,.wiki ul li a')).css("font-size", "+=2!important");
      $("#font-size").text(size += 2);
    }
  });

  $(".fontSizeMinus").on("click", function() {
    if ((size - 1) >= 14) {
      $($('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a span,#menu li a,.right-description,.right-description a,.newsboard h4,.event-right-description h3 a,.event-right-description span,span.heading-text,.heading-text,.recent-files ul li a,.recent-files ul li span,.forums ul li span,.forums ul li a,.activity-feed ul li span,.activity-feed ul li a,.wiki ul li span,.wiki ul li a')).css("font-size", "-=2");
      $("#font-size").text(size -= 2);
    }
  });

  $(".fontSizeNormal").on("click", function() {
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>l`enter code here`i>a span,#menu li a,.right-description,.right-description a,.newsboard h4,.event-right-description h3 a,.event-right-description span,span.heading-text,.heading-text,.recent-files ul li a,.recent-files ul li span,.forums ul li span,.forums ul li a,.activity-feed ul li span,.activity-feed ul li a,.wiki ul li span,.wiki ul li a').css("font-size", '');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There will always be `<body></body>` tags in the HTML output. If you can't see them in your page it's likely that it's because the content is injected in to a template which has them. In either case, the issue is largely moot. Just put the jQuery logic in a document.ready event handler to ensure it runs *after* the DOM has loaded.

Comment: you mean like this?  <script>
$(document).ready(function () { 

function getSize() {}});

Comment: That's correct.